# How can I subtract two integers datewise in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has years as int, say 202101. I want to get the difference in months with 202205.

For example 202205 - 202101 = 16 (months).

Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Convert to a `date` and then use `DATEDIFF`; ideally you should be storing your date data *as* a date and time data type in the first place. Then treating your dates as a `date` is *significantly* easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on Larnu's comment.

```
select datediff(month
      ,try_convert(date,concat(202101,'01'))
      ,try_convert(date,concat(202205,'01'))
      )
```

**Results**

```
16
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do integer division by `100` you get the year component with the remainder as the month component so another method is

```
DECLARE @Date1 INT =202205, @Date2 INT = 202101

SELECT  (12 * (@Date1/100 - @Date2/100)) + (@Date1 % 100 - @Date2 % 100)
```